# Redirecting to a page if session object expires or user did not login to the application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is a mvc application

I have the links below on my master page

Link1 Link2 Link3   signout signIn

I have a userprofile object that is populated
when authentication is done.

When the session object for the user expires
and I click on the links, I get the yellow page(error page).

I will prefer a situation where when you click on the
links and the session object is expired, you get 
redirected to the signin page.

Soln A: I could solve this problem by writing a method
which test for null value of the userprofile object then
make a call to this method on the click on every link.

I dont want this approach because in the future if there
are new controllers, i will need to care for them.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a Base Controller than all of your other controllers inherit from.  Within this I would have a

```
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        if (SessionManager.Instance() == null)
        {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary 
                {
                    { "Controller", "BaseController" },
                    { "Action", "LogOn" }
                });

        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

The OnAction Executing will be hit before any method in any of your controllers - this way you can check your session is valid or your user is valid or whatever and handle the redirect to the view you want if that is not the case.  If you do a Google search for Filters Actions MVC you will find out much more info.